# class '_mysql_exceptions.DataError': How to check a variable type in an if condition

Tags: python, mysql-python

I need to return update/insert result, from the database class, back to the calling class to differentiate 
 between success and error.
An update/insert returns `<type long'>` while a database error returns
 `<class '_mysql_exceptions.DataError'>`.
Since I am not sure about the return type during a success that it would always be a long type, I am checking for type class.
And, I couldn't do it. I tried these:

```
 try:
   x = cursor.execute(q, d)
   conn.commit()
   return x   #Return this to the calling class
 except MySQLdb.Error, e:
   return e   #Return this to the calling class

 if isinstance(e, class): #Doesn't work
 if issubclass(e, _mysql_exceptions): #Doesn't work
```

How do I check the type of `e` here?
If I am doing it all wrong, please suggest something nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `isinstance(obj, class)` is not valid syntax, and `_mysql_exceptions` is a module, not an exception type, which raises a `TypeError`. To explicitly check an exception type, you can catch each individually:

```py
from _mysql.exceptions import DataError, SomeOtherError, ...
from requests import HTTPError # as an example of a different error

try:
    x = cursor.execute(q, d)
    conn.commit()
except DataError as e:
    # do something
except SomeOtherError as e:
    # do something else
except HTTPError as e:
    # your connection is broken
    # maybe raise from e?
```

You need to catch that explicit error type, then you don't need to do `if isinstance`. Start with no exception handling at all, this will lead you to the exceptions that you *do* need to handle, and anything else should be considered unexpected and should cause the application to either crash or propagate some helpful error message to let you know something bad happened:

```py
try:
    some_function()
except ValueError as e:
    # this is expected, and is handled accordingly
    handle_expected_error()

# This is optional, normally a bare exception block is considered bad practice,
# but can allow your application to continue functioning while raising some
# helpful error so this isn't suppressed
except Exception as e:
    # this is not expected, I'm going to propagate this error
    # up to be obvious what happened
    handle_unexpected_error()
    #or
    raise from e
```

### Edit: What if I want a calling class to handle the exception?

Reasonable, and I would lean on catching the exception. Instead of handling the exception, I would allow the function to just raise the exception and handle it in the calling class. As a really simple example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, conn, cursor):
        self.conn = conn
        self.cursor = cursor

    def some_function(self):
        # This raises an error, note I'm not handling it here
        x = self.cursor.execute()
        self.conn.commit()
        return x

    def main_function(self):
        try:
            x = self.some_function()
        except DataError as e:
            handle_exception()
        # unexpected, handle this here
        except Exception as e:
            raise from e
            # or do something else
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Sir. Just like you have said, I, too, am not trying to handle exception. All I do is return the success(`x`)/error(`e`) to the calling class. ( Please see edit to the code, I have replaced print with return). Now, in the calling class, I am trying to identify the returned value as a success or error based on the `type`. And, this error/success would be returned to the client as it is. Awaiting for your advice here...

Comment: I gotcha, again I think catching the exception is the way to go here. You can `raise` from the function and catch in the outer calling class. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. I did not know that I could handle the exceptions this way, learned something new. I have tested it a lot and it works nicely.